# Maximizing $\frac{\gcd(m,n)}{k}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, contest-math

I am having difficulty finishing the proof.

---

**Problem:** Let $m=96^{96}+96!$ and $n=(96^{96}-96!)^k-1,$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Find the maximum value of $\frac{\gcd(m,n)}{k}.$

---

**Solution:** First of all, Wilson's Theorem combined with Fermat's Little Theorem gives $m\equiv 0\pmod{97}$ and $n\equiv 2^k-1\pmod{97}.$ From here, we note that if $n\equiv 2^k-1\equiv 0\pmod{97},$ and $k\leq 96,$ then $k\mid 96.$ Through any one of a variety of methods, we arrive at $48\mid k.$

Now, from here the claim is that $m\equiv n\equiv 0\pmod{191}.$ However, I haven't been able to prove this yet. I am thinking this is some more modular arithmetic manipulation.

The part I am fully stuck on is the further claim is that $97$ and $191$ are the *only* possible prime divisors of both $m$ and $n.$

This would give us a maximum value of $\gcd(m,n)=97\cdot 191=18527$ at a minimum $k=48.$ Checking that $\frac{18527}{48}>191$ (since if not, the $k=1$ case would be larger), gives the answer of $\boxed{\frac{18527}{48}}.$

Comment: $(96^{96})^2=96^{192}\equiv96^2\bmod{191}$ by Fermat. Working mod $191$, $-1\equiv190!=(1\times2\times\cdots\times95)(190\times189\times\cdots\times96)\equiv(95!)(-95!)$ so $(95!)^2\equiv1\bmod{191}$ so $(96!)^2\equiv96^2\bmod{191}$. So, $(96!)^2\equiv(96^{96})^2\bmod{191}$, so $96!\equiv\pm96^{96}\bmod{191}$. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, that definitely proves the first claim.