# When is the $\gcd$ not prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

This is an extension of a previous question ([Maximizing $\frac{\gcd(m,n)}{k}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410717/maximizing-frac-gcdm-nk)) which is interesting.

Let $m=(p-1)^{p-1}+(p-1)!$ and let $n=((p-1)^{p-1}-(p-1)!)^{p-1}-1.$

For which odd primes is $\gcd(m,n)\neq p?$

For simplicity, let $d=\gcd(m,n).$ Then, we very easily see that $p\mid d.$ However, through some experimentation on Wolfram Alpha, I found that for *most* primes, $d=p,$ but not for all. The first few primes that satisfy the requirements are $S=\{5,31,41,43,53,71,97,\ldots\}$ (I hope I didn't miss one). This is not a known sequence according to OEIS. I am curious how exactly to find these primes.

Two other things to note. First, we see that if $p\in S$ then $d=p(2p-3)$ and $2p-3$ is prime. However, not all primes $p$ such that $2p-3$ is prime are in $S$, for example $p=13$ and $2p-3=23.$

Moreover, I also found that if $p\in S$ then it is not necessarily true that $2p-3\in S.$ Indeed, $2p-3\not \in S$ for the first few $p\in S,$ but the first example is $97$ and $191,$ which are both in $S.$

**Edit:** As noted by user dezdichado in the comments, we see that $S\subset \{p \in\mathbb{P}\mid 2p-3 \in \mathbb{P}\},$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of prime numbers. Obviously, this is a weaker condition, but it would be interesting to see the proof of this.

Comment: So what you are saying is basically $$S\subseteq\{p\in\mathbb{P}\vert\,\, 2p-3\in\mathbb{P}\}$$
with strict inclusion? I would be surprised if this problem is not as hard as any other twin-prime type problem, if not harder.

Comment: $S$ is a strict subset of that, since if $p\in S,$ then $2p-3\in \mathbb{P},$ but not all $p\in \mathbb{P}$ such that $2p-3\in \mathbb{P}$ are in $S.$ Is there a way to show why the $2p-3$ condition is true?

Comment: some more terms of the sequence: 5,31,41,43,53,71,97,101,107,127,167,191,193,241,251,317,331,373,421,431,433,443,487... curiously, it seems that no $p$ ends with a $9$...

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé: not that surprising. If $p$ ends with a 9 then $2p-3$ ends with a $5$ thus cannot be prime.

Comment: @AndreaMori 
Funny because I was about to write "surprisingly", but I decided to go with "curiously" instead because I had the feeling that it wouldn't be a big surprise! But thanks for the explanation!